# RCB trip / switch-on can cause Pi to brick?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

I have a Pi which is powered by a (official) Pi Power Adaptor (from Amazon).

A few days ago, an electrician working in my hose switched off (by accident) and  turned an RCB back on.

I believe that this may have caused a power surge and damaged my Pi, but I am not 100% sure.

I have seen Cisco Phones go dead after a power was restored after an outage, while their power supplies were not damaged.

Has anyone else seen such behaviour on a Pi ?

If so, can anyone recommend a good way to protect this from happening ? (Not sure power strips with surge protectors are any good).

Comment: Forgot to mention its a Pi3

Answer (score 1):

I will be honest I unplagged my Pi few times from the wall without shutting it down properly so I dont think it caused any damage but worst case scenario just try another SD card because this things are fragile if they are low quality...

Comment: Thanks, but I did try that as well. The card in the damaged Pi did work without any issues in a new replacement Pi I bought however.
I ended up returning the damaged one to the store and getting a replacement.